# multi-parent hierarchy propagation in SQL/DAX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

Suppose I have a table that describes primary and secondary reporting lines for each member of staff. Let's imagine an organisational structure where the CEO, employee `0`, has 2 managers (`1` and `2`) reporting to him.

Manager `2` has 2 staff in her team (`3` and `4`), however staff member `4` actually works in Manager `1`'s timezone, so while he has `2` as his primary report, he also reports to Manager `1` as a Secondary report so that `1` can fullfil normal fiduciary managerial obligations (provide support, etc.).

In addition to taking a secondary management role for employee `4`, Manager `2` also has a team member reporting to him (`5`).

**Edit:** To illustrate the multi-parent problem, let's give team member `4` an intern, staff member `6`. **Team member `6` is now the subordinate of both managers `1` and `2`** - the latter being inherited through the secondary reporting line.

The organisational structure would look like this:

```
+--+-------+---------+
|ID|Primary|Secondary|
|0 |NULL   |NULL     |
|1 |0      |NULL     |
|2 |0      |NULL     |
|3 |1      |NULL     |
|4 |1      |2        |
|5 |2      |NULL     |
|6 |4      |NULL     |
+--+-------+---------+
```

Now I want to expand this into a SQL view that gives me a list of people *below* any given staff member, covering both primary and secondary reports. So for staff member `2` (the manager with a primary and secondary report), I would expect to see team members `4` and `5`, and for the CEO (`0`) I'd expect to see ever staff member other than the CEO. Our new intern, `6`, is the subordinate of the CEO, managers `1` and `2`, as well as his direct manager, `4`.

This would look like this:

```
+--+-----------+
|ID|Subordinate|
|0 |1          |
|0 |2          |
|0 |3          |
|0 |4          |
|0 |5          |
|0 |6          |
|1 |3          |
|1 |4          |
|1 |6          |
|2 |4          |
|2 |5          |
|2 |6          |
|4 |6          |
+--+-----------+
```

How would I achieve this in SQL? I'm thinking some kind of `OUTER APPLY` operation on the ID but I'm struggling to get my head around the reentrancy that would be required (I think) to solve this. My background is in procedural programming, which I think is part of the reason I'm struggling here.

**NB**: An obvious question that I'd like to anticipate here is *"Surely this is an XY problem - why on earth would you want to do this?"*

I want to use [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-rls) in PowerBI to give each staff member access to certain information about individuals below them in the organisational structure. Unfortunately RLS doesn't permit the execution of stored procedures per individual, so I'm stuck with doing this combinatorial expansion and then simply filtering the above table based on the login.

Having said that, I'm open to better ways of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result you want in SQL, the easiest way to achieve this is to use a recursive CTE.

In the example below I divide the work into two CTEs.  The first transforms the set into pairs of managers and subordinates.  The second CTE gets all results from the first, and then joins to itself using UNION ALL where the manager from the first CTE is a subordinate in the recursive CTE.  This will keep repeating until there are no matches that can be made.

Because it's possible that a subordinate has more than one manager, duplicate rows can be returned for each ancestor.  Because of that DISTINCT is used when returning results from the recursive CTE.

```
WITH all_reports AS (
    SELECT [Primary] [ManagerID], ID [Subordinate]
    FROM tbl
    WHERE [Primary] IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT [Secondary], ID
    FROM tbl
    WHERE [Secondary] IS NOT NULL
)
, recursive_cte AS (
    SELECT ManagerID, Subordinate
    FROM all_reports
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ancestor.ManagerID, descendant.Subordinate
    FROM recursive_cte ancestor
    INNER JOIN all_reports descendant ON descendant.ManagerID = ancestor.Subordinate
)
SELECT DISTINCT ManagerID, Subordinate
FROM recursive_cte
```

If you want the distance between manager and subordinate then rewrite the recursive CTE as follows:

```
SELECT ManagerID, Subordinate, 1 [Distance]
FROM all_reports
UNION ALL
SELECT ancestor.ManagerID, descendant.Subordinate, ancestor.Distance + 1
FROM recursive_cte ancestor
INNER JOIN all_reports descendant ON descendant.ManagerID = ancestor.Subordinate
```

Comment: Cheers this works as expected. One thing I don't understand is what the stopping condition is for the recursion. Why doesn't the `INNER JOIN` of `ancestor` on `descendant` cause an infinite loop?

Comment: That can be a problem, however what helps is that in each iteration its only going to send the rows from the last iteration.  So as long as you don't have a situation in the hierarchy where a descendant can be a manager of one of its ancestor's managers then you'll be fine.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty easily solved using the Parent-Child Hierarchy functions in DAX. I don't think you need to build any extra tables, just stick the following conditions in your RLS rules:

For Employee `N`, you just need to check if

```
PATHCONTAINS(PATH('Hierarchy'[ID], 'Hierarchy'[Primary]), N)
```

or

```
PATHCONTAINS(PATH('Hierarchy'[ID], 'Hierarchy'[Secondary]), N)
```

Note that this allows Employee `N` to see themselves as well as their subordinates, but you can add an extra condition if you don't want that.

---

**Edit:** When your structure is not a tree, the problem becomes more difficult. Here's an approach that should work.

For each `ID`, find the subordinates to get `Level1`, search `Level1` for the next level of subordinates, and so forth until no subordinates exist. (If you have a loop in your structure that returns you to a higher level, then you'll get stuck in recursion.)

In this case, there are three levels below the top so we need three steps.

```
| ID | Primary | Secondary | Level1 | Level2 | Level3 |
|----|---------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
| 0  |         |           | 1      | 4      | 6      |
| 0  |         |           | 2      | 4      | 6      |
| 0  |         |           | 2      | 5      |        |
| 0  |         |           | 3      |        |        |
| 1  | 0       |           | 4      | 6      |        |
| 2  | 0       |           | 4      | 6      |        |
| 2  | 0       |           | 5      |        |        |
| 3  | 0       |           |        |        |        |
| 4  | 1       | 2         | 6      |        |        |
| 5  | 2       |           |        |        |        |
| 6  | 4       |           |        |        |        |
```

Here's the M code to do this in the Power Query Editor:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows({{0,null,null},{1,0,null},{2,0,null},{3,0,null},{4,1,2},{5,2,null},{6,4,null}},{"ID", "Primary", "Secondary"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Primary", Int64.Type}, {"Secondary", Int64.Type}}),
    SearchNextLevel = ExpandNext(ExpandNext(ExpandNext(#"Changed Type", "Level1", "ID"), "Level2", "Level1"), "Level3", "Level2"),
    #"Appended Query" =
        Table.Combine(
            {Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(SearchNextLevel, {"ID", "Level1"}), {"Level1","Subordinate"}),
             Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(SearchNextLevel, {"ID", "Level2"}), {"Level2","Subordinate"}),
             Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(SearchNextLevel, {"ID", "Level3"}), {"Level3","Subordinate"})}
        ),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Appended Query", each ([Subordinate] <> null)),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}, {"Subordinate", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Here's the custom function that's used multiple times to expand to the next level:

```
let
    ExpandToNextLevel = (T as table, NextLevel as text, ThisLevel as text) as table =>
    let
        SearchNextLevel =
        Table.AddColumn(T,
            NextLevel,
            (C) =>
                Table.SelectRows(
                    T, each Record.Field(C, ThisLevel) <> null and
                       ([Primary] = Record.Field(C, ThisLevel) or
                        [Secondary] = Record.Field(C, ThisLevel))
                    )[ID]
        ),
        ExpandColumn = Table.ExpandListColumn(SearchNextLevel, NextLevel)
    in
        ExpandColumn
in
    ExpandToNextLevel
```

To make this general, I obviously need to put the expanding and appending into a recursive loop. I'll come back to this as time permits.

---

**Edit:** Here's a recursive version of the query which uses unpivoting instead of appending.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows({{0,null,null},{1,0,null},{2,0,null},{3,0,null},{4,1,2},{5,2,null},{6,4,null}},{"ID", "Primary", "Secondary"}),
    #"Changed Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Primary", Int64.Type}, {"Secondary", Int64.Type}}),
    IDCount = List.Count(List.Distinct(#"Changed Types"[ID])),
    RecursiveExpand = List.Generate(
        () => [i=0, InputTable = #"Changed Types"],
        each [i] < IDCount and
             List.NonNullCount(List.Last(Table.ToColumns([InputTable]))) > 0,
        each [
             CurrentLevel = if [i] = 0 then "ID" else "Level" & Text.From([i]),
             NextLevel = if [i] = 0 then "Level1" else "Level" & Text.From([i]+1),
             InputTable = ExpandNext([InputTable], NextLevel, CurrentLevel),
             i = [i] + 1
        ]
    ),
    FinalTable = List.Last(RecursiveExpand)[InputTable],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(FinalTable, {"Secondary", "Primary", "ID"}, "Level", "Subordinate"),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"ID", "Subordinate"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}, {"Subordinate", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

It will keep expanding levels until expanding to the next level produces all nulls or hits the maximum number of levels to prevent infinite looping.

Comment: What if `4` has a primary subordinate? In that case I'd want them to show up as a subordinate of `2` as well, but that wouldn't work with the above as the lines are treated as separate.

Comment: So your hierarchy is not a tree then and there is no unique path upward. That definitely makes things more difficult. I'd recommend editing your post to add this example (i.e. add a `6,4,NULL` row).

Comment: Yeah that's right - I have added an intern (staff `6`) whose manager has primary and secondary reports, which illustrates this requirement. Apologies for not making this clear enough before.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to flatten out both the reporting hierarchy and the secondary-reporting hierarchy, loading them into separate tables in the tabular model.

See [DAX Patterns: Parent-Child Hierarchies](https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/) for how to do this completely in DAX.  Or you can use a SQL Server query using a Recursive Common Table Expression to flatten the two hierarchies.

In either case these become two seperate tables in the model, and two separate relationships, which you can then reference in your RLS filters.

Comment: In my example they're not separate though. See my comment on Alexis Olson's answer.

Comment: Well, there is a general solution to this sort of problem: materialize all pairs in the relation.  So for each employee have a row for each other employee that employee can see.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping to achieve, (see the last table in my question) but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Simple way to store, imho. All int. Only a join point but will fill all needs that I can see expressed with room for great flexibility in all directions. Project can be either a small project or a grouping of projects and even department/company hierarchy. Seems like dynamic and adaptable are a priority or sorts.

```
+--+-------+---------+-------+--------+
|ID|project|over     |under  |level   |
|0 |14     |0        |9      |1       |
|1 |53     |4        |1      |2       |
|2 |4      |4        |4      |2       |
|3 |1      |4        |2      |3       |
|4 |1      |0        |7      |1       |
|5 |2      |4        |6      |1       |
|6 |4      |4        |8      |5       |
+--+-------+---------+-------+--------+
```

An example of using project in an expanded way would be adding an ongoing "Mission Statement" project for a dept/company/facility/office/room/vendor/position or any other "grouping" you can think of where a hierarchy resolution is desired. Why make life more complicated? Worst thing you may someday need to do is offload the entries for completed projects into an archive of some sort if the need for historic information is necessary.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) It's not really clear to me what this response is saying. Unless you're able to clarify it I'm going to flag this.

Comment: as a linking table providing functionality, may not be what you are looking for but it's what I would do if presented with the same problem allowing for future scope creep or just extended functionality.

Comment: not a dax solution, just t-sql, 80% is just inner joins to get to the info desired, entry points from wherever you desire to initiate, from the person, project, relationship level. been a sql dev for nearing 20 years now, started in sql 2000, around 1999, so I look to sql first and start as simple as possible. I did not give queries because entry points are so plentiful and it felt too obvious, didn't mean to seem obfuscating. please accept my apologies for intruding. I'll get my footing here as time wears on and thanks for the welcome! :)